# I have doubts wether urine splashes came to me or not

Tags: sharia, fatwa, doubts, fatwa-explanation

while urinating sometimes i get doubts wether urine drops splashes came to me or not iam not sure about it so do i have ro change my trouser and wash my feet

Comment: Then stop peeing in a standing position. As this is basically disliked.

Comment: i dont urinate in a standing position

Comment: Then why the doubts?

Comment: @Medi1Saif♦ because in india we use the indian toilet when we urinate sometime splashes come

Comment: Well as long as you arw sure you didn't pee on your clothes this is the safest way to do it. And therefore there's no need for worries.